# Spring Session Cookie shows wrong value

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-session

I am looking into spring sessions, going through docs i was able to create table and persist my session there, and as i can see spring adds `SESSION` cookie but it's value is totally different from session id value in db.

[image]
[image]

On first screen you can see session id in db and on second cookie value from browser. While debugging i can see that HttpSession.getId() returns value that is in DB. I wonder why these values are different and how spring knows which session to return? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2.0, Spring Session uses Base64 encoded session cookies by default. You can change this default value by configuring  DefaultCookieSerializer and set useBase64Encoding to false.

```
    @Bean
    fun cookieSerializer() :  CookieSerializer {
        val serializer = DefaultCookieSerializer()
        serializer.setCookieName("JSESSIONID")
        serializer.setCookiePath("/")
        serializer.setDomainNamePattern("^.+?\\.(\\w+\\.[a-z]+)$")
        serializer.setUseBase64Encoding(false)
        return serializer
    }
```